# Problems creating WAR file (Access is denied) (and the archive is probably corrupt but I could not delete it)

Tags: eclipse, ant

Here is the error I'm having trying to build something in Eclipse 3.8 on Windows 7 Pro:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\path\to\build.xml:140: Problem creating war: C:\path\to\war\abc.war (Access is denied) (and the archive is probably corrupt but I could not delete it)

Total time: 1 second
```

I found this already:
[problems creating war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827973/problems-creating-war-file)

However, I'm running Eclipse as Administrator. In theory, wouldn't this rule out UAC? How about anti-virus?

Eclipse is also installed in the following path:
`C:\Users\me\MyCustomApps\eclipse-indigo\eclipse\workspace`

Comment: Is the .war file being used by another process (like Tomcat)?

Comment: No, but you just helped me figure out the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .war file was being written in a folder on the workstation. This folder was shared with a local CentOS VMWare instance. I had a terminal in CentOS that had that path loaded due to the fact that I had recently copied the .war file to my webapps folder.

I simply navigated away from this shared folder in the CentOS terminal window and was able to build the war file without any issues in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same frustrating issue.  My solution was, in Eclipse, disable the "Build Automatically" option under the Project menu...which kept regenerating the WAR file.  After that, and a restart of Eclipse (not sure if that was needed), I noticed the file no longer existed in my workspace under that project.  It showed up one last time under my Eclipse project, but at that point I was simply able to delete it and run a Maven Clean, which was successful.  I hope that helps.
Eugene

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. A Maven clean install created the target folder with Unknown user credentials. Normally deleting the target folder should solve the issue. In my case a system reboot let me delete the target folder and do a republish.

I was working in a CentOS terminal. Cygwin interferes with windows credentials which causes this Unknown user problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. I increase the Heap Space in eclipse.ini file inside Eclipse folder and resolved the issue.  `-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m`

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows environment variables set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m.
Then in Eclipse Set: Run Configuration -> Maven Build -> (select you Maven Launcher) -> Environment -> Append environment to native environment

It will work for me...

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this issue, please deleted the existing war in the location and check whether the `jboss` instance is running or not. If it is running please stop the server and then do clean build of the `projetc`. Uncheck the build automatically in Eclipse.

It will work :)